# unitary operator and existence of $T=U^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that if T is a unitary operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space V, then T has a unitary square root; that is, there exists a unitary operator U such that $T=U^2$.

Concept question: I think I am missing some concept here. I can't think how is the proof related to eigenvalues. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes; a matrix is unitary if and only if it is orthogonally diagonalizable and all eigenvalues have complex norm $1$.